# Insert new row while update batch in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am getting an issue, i dont know how to insert new row while update batch in codeigniter.Here is my update batch code, working fine but need assistance about inserting new row.

```php
$input_data = $this->input->post();
for($i = 0; $i < sizeof($input_data['iid']); $i++) {
    $batch[] = array(
        'id'            =>  $input_data['iid'][$i],
        'desc'          =>  $input_data['desc'][$i],
        'size'          =>  $input_data['size'][$i],
        'stock'         =>  $input_data['stock'][$i],   
        'color'         =>  $input_data['color'][$i],
        'qty'           =>  $input_data['qty'][$i], 
        'price'         =>  $input_data['price'][$i],
        'linetotal'     =>  $input_data['linetotal'][$i],
    );
}

$this->db->update_batch('invoice_data', $batch, 'id');
$this->session->set_flashdata('success', 'Data added successfully.');
$this->session->set_flashdata('id', $id);
redirect('invoices');
```

[image]

But when i add new row with new data it will do nothing. Even dont add new row id. Please help

Comment: I assume that new data won't actually have an `id`? In which case split the insert and update batches?

Comment: @Jonnix then how can i achieve this. Please elaborate

Comment: Well, you can't update rows that don't exist, so my suggestion is to create 2 arrays, $updateBatch, and $insertBatch, which you add to depending on whether an ID is set or not (depends on your code / app). Then use update_batch on $updateBatch, and insert_batch on $insertBatch.

Comment: Okayyyy...Let me try then i will let you know.

Comment: @Jonnix if you can make an example code it will be really thankful to you.

Answer (score 0):

this will work if you are using array in inputs
like this
    `<input type="text" name="size[]">`

```
function save_data() {
    if (isset($_POST['size']) && !empty($_POST['size'])) { // you can  take any field excluding id 
        foreach ($_POST['size'] as $key => $value) {
            $batch = array();
            $batch['desc'] = $_POST['desc'][$key];
            $batch['size'] = $_POST['size'][$key];
            $batch['stock'] = $_POST['stock'][$key];
            $batch['color'] = $_POST['color'][$key];
            $batch['qty'] = $_POST['qty'][$key];
            $batch['price'] = $_POST['price'][$key];
            $batch['linetotal'] = $_POST['linetotal'][$key];
            if (isset($_POST['id'][$key]) && !empty($_POST['id'][$key])) { // if your id is blank means new data otherwise update it with given id
                $id = $_POST['id'][$key];
                $this->db->update_batch('invoice_data', $batch, 'id');  //pass id in it
            } else {
                $this->db->insert('invoice_data', $batch);
            }
        }
        $this->session->set_flashdata('success', 'Data added/updated successfully.');
        redirect('invoices');
    }
}
```

Comment: i am gettting two errors after running your code.One is " Invalid argument supplied for foreach()" and the other one is "One or more rows submitted for batch updating is missing the specified index.". Please check

Comment: please show me your html part.
first error is coming because , function's not getting input in array format. as i said earlier 'name attribute of input should be in array format
<input type="text" name="size[]"> 
you need to **$id** variable while updating the rows.. (in update_batch() function)